# Contact Us Form results in DMARC error with a Yahoo email address

Tags: bug

I tried to send an email through the Contact Us page on the main site.  I got a bounceback complaining of a DMARC violation.

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

      echo@stackoverflow.com
        SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
        host aspmx.l.google.com [74.125.22.26]: 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's
        550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if
        550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
        550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC
        550 5.7.1 initiative. h8si54085058qgh.33 - gsmtp   team@stackoverflow.com
        SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
        host aspmx.l.google.com [173.194.205.26]: 550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's
        550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if
        550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
        550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC
        550 5.7.1 initiative. 47si54054807qga.86 - gsmtp
```

It then listed the contents and headers of the message.

Comment: What results did you have from reading the link in the error? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690

Comment: Everything in that link is about what to do if I either sent that email from a Yahoo email client or about changing the DMARC policy for the Yahoo domain.  Since I didn't send it from the Yahoo client (SO's contact page tried to impersonate me to send the message from my email account it seems) and I don't control the Yahoo domain, it isn't really relevant.

Comment: "550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com" -- The error message sure seems to think it is coming from Yahoo.

Comment: Which is why I'm thinking the contact us page is trying to use my email to send the message.  Hence the DMARC error.

Comment: Of course it is trying to use your email address to send the message.

Comment: And that is the problem.  SO's server isn't one of Yahoo's authorized mail servers and thus can't send an email from a Yahoo email address without looking like a phishing email.  Gmail sees that, checks the DMARC policy for Yahoo and rejects the email.  As long as they are trying to send the email from an address they don't have rights to send from, it will always set this off.  Any other domain with a similar DMARC policy will have the same problem.

Comment: Use a real email provider. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2141120/yahoo-email-antispoofing-policy-breaks-mailing-lists.html